# Using .NET how to convert ISO 8859-1 encoded text files that contain Latin-1 accented characters to UTF-8

Tags: c#, utf-8, iso-8859-1, latin1

I am being sent text files saved in [ISO 88591-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) format that contain accented characters from the Latin-1 range (as well as normal ASCII a-z, etc.). How do I convert these files to [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) using C# so that the single-byte accented characters in ISO 8859-1 become valid UTF-8 characters?

I have tried to use a StreamReader with ASCIIEncoding, and then converting the ASCII string to UTF-8 by instantiating encoding `ascii` and encoding `utf8` and then using `Encoding.Convert(ascii, utf8, ascii.GetBytes( asciiString) )` — but the accented characters are being rendered as question marks.

What step am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried using a StreamWriter with UTF8 encoding to write the asciiString out to a text file? Does that do it?

Comment: @Task: His issue is that he's never getting the string out of 8859-1, not that he can't save it in UTF-8.

Comment: Oh, that's completely his problem, no question.  I just find it easier to debug text conversion with a StreamReader/StreamWriter pair (so I can see the in/out files) rather than with an Encoding.Convert call.  That might be just me.

Comment: @Task: I agree (hence my answer!) ;)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to get the proper `Encoding` object. ASCII is just as it's named: ASCII, meaning that it only supports 7-bit ASCII characters. If what you want to do is convert files, then this is likely easier than dealing with the byte arrays directly.

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName,
                                       Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
{
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(
                                           outFileName, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

However, if you want to have the byte arrays yourself, it's easy enough to do with `Encoding.Convert`.

```
byte[] converted = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"), 
    Encoding.UTF8, data);
```

It's important to note here, however, that if you want to go down this road then you should *not* use an encoding-based string reader like `StreamReader` for your file IO. `FileStream` would be better suited, as it will read the actual bytes of the files.

In the interest of fully exploring the issue, something like this would work:

```
using (System.IO.FileStream input = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName,
                                    System.IO.FileMode.Open, 
                                    System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[input.Length];

    int readLength = 0;

    while (readLength < buffer.Length) 
        readLength += input.Read(buffer, readLength, buffer.Length - readLength);

    byte[] converted = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"), 
                       Encoding.UTF8, buffer);

    using (System.IO.FileStream output = new System.IO.FileStream(outFileName,
                                         System.IO.FileMode.Create, 
                                         System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
    {
        output.Write(converted, 0, converted.Length);
    }
}
```

In this example, the `buffer` variable gets filled with the actual data in the file as a `byte[]`, so no conversion is done. `Encoding.Convert` specifies a source and destination encoding, then stores the converted bytes in the variable named...`converted`. This is then written to the output file directly.

Like I said, the first option using `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` will be much simpler if this is all you're doing, but the latter example should give you more of a hint as to what's actually going on.

Comment: thanks to all for the help and esp @Adam for his thorough answer

Answer (score 17):

If the files are relatively small (say, ~10 megabytes), you'll only need two lines of code:

```
  string txt = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(inpPath, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
  System.IO.File.WriteAllText(outPath, txt);
```

Comment: Why does your solution only work when the file being read is less than 10 megabytes?

Comment: @bit ReadAllText uses a StreamReader which has a default buffer size of 1024 which you might want to tweak for larger files https://web.archive.org/web/20230801072915/https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs