# TextBox in Windows Forms does not display Unicode characters

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, unicode

I have a Unicode character in the settings of a VB.NET application.

[image: unicode in settings]

With the following code:

```
CurrencyText.Text = My.Settings.Options_Display_Currency
```

I try to render this value in a text box with Calibri font, I see a box like this:

[image]

How to enable the Windows Form to display Unicode characters?

Comment: Something is borken in your machine setup.  When the default font doesn't contain a glyph, Windows goes looking for another font that has the glyph and uses it instead.  Works fine for TextBox and clearly you do have such a font.  This is registry stuff, ask about this at superuser.com

Comment: @HansPassant Calibri didn't show that character. When I switched the Font to Arial, the Unicode character displayed properly.

Comment: Well, that wasn't the point.  I can use a TextBox with Font = Calibri on my machine and it has no trouble showing glyphs that are not in that font.  As it is supposed to.  Which is why I commented that there's something wrong with your machine.

Comment: Oh Okay. Thanks. Is there a way to figure what is wrong so I can fix it and also fix in all my customer's system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means the font used to display the character doesn't contain glyph for the character. Try a font like Arial or any font listed here http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/fontsupport.htm

Answer (score 1):

Change your TextBox with a RichTextBox and it will probably work.
also [Default encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/592925/1471381) can be helpful.