# Append Data to each row in a CSV File VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, csv

I have as csv file with a header.  I need to loop through all of the lines in the csv and on each one append an additional column at the very end.  I would like to not have to read the line in each because when it gets re-written it seems to change data.  I have a weird field with symbols so it doesn't read it right.  I know this has to be easy but I have spent two days researching options, and have not found the answer.  I am on a huge time crunch to get this finished up today.  Any suggestions?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does it have to be with VB.Net?... Truly Excel might be even faster... Open it in Excel, add in the extra column and re-save as csv.... Just a different idea...

Comment: As another option, your streamreader can deal with different encodings which would stop the problem of your symbols being converted... Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592824/c-sharp-help-reading-foreign-characters-using-streamreader

Comment: If you read and write to the same file at the same time it will cause problems. You could write into a temporary file and at the end overwrite the file.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, if your data is getting mangled somehow then it's most likely an encoding issue.  The answer to your problem is extremely simple, e.g.

```
Dim filePath As String
Dim encoding As Encoding
Dim newColumnHeader As String

'...

Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath, encoding)

lines(0) &= "," & newColumnHeader

For lineNumber = 1 To lines.GetUpperBound(0)
    lines(lineNumber) &= "," & lineNumber
Next

File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines, encoding)
```