# Use UTF-8 in .NET windows application

Tags: .net, utf-8, character-encoding, internationalization, textbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unicode characters not showing in System.Windows.Forms.TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420659/unicode-characters-not-showing-in-system-windows-forms-textbox)

I'm trying to render international languages within a textbox inside my .net windows application but it's not showing the characters properly.

I can't seem to find the setting to change the character encoding to UTF-8, can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks :)

Comment: check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420659/unicode-characters-not-showing-in-system-windows-forms-textbox

Comment: Ok, so the answer marked on that link was to change to a Rich Text Box. Even though a "TextBox" should display System.String values which are apparently UTF-16 by default, the different language characters will only render properly in a **Rich**TextBox? Is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.String` in .NET is already Unicode (UTF-16) encoded. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx#Remarks) states: "A string is a sequential collection of Unicode characters that is used to represent text."

Comment: UTF-16 encoded. But close enough.

Comment: So it should just work. I need to look at something else maybe? The installed fonts?