# Drag'n'Dropping text into TextBox and special characters

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I made drag'n'drop support for `TextBox` control, but here are some problems with charsets (on special characters).

If I drop that text on my control:

> Cześć, chciałbym przetestować specjalne polskie znaki.

It becomes:

> CzeĹ›Ä‡, chciaĹ‚bym przetestowaÄ‡ specjalne polskie znaki.

Here is my code for `DragDrop`:

```cs
private void textBox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
    {
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
        txt.Text = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text);;
    }
    else e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
}
```

When I paste data, everything seems to be ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `DataFormats.UnicodeText` instead of `DataFormats.Text`?

Comment: What is the source of the drag'n'drop operation (i.e. where are you dragging the data from)? The issue might be that the source uses different encoding than the target.

Comment: Did you change `DataFormats.Text` to `DataFormats.UnicodeText` in **both** places (you have two occurrences of that in your code)? I have reproduced this issue using Chrome but replacing Text with UnicodeText in both lines helped me.

Answer (score 1):

from this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420659/unicode-characters-not-showing-in-system-windows-forms-textbox)

1. Try using RichTextBox instead of checkbox and see if it works then - that way you know that you at least read data properly.